# How to access specific object in JSON using Angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, data-binding

I'm trying to access certain data from an API and having trouble doing so. Here is the structure of the JSON from the API:

[image]

I'm wanting to access `Name`, `StateName` & `CityName` within `value` to iterate through a table. I'm getting the obvious error "Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays", because ngFor isn't iterating through the array. How can I fix my code to iterate through the data to fill my table?

component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.css']
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {

  customer: any;

 constructor(private Service: CustomerDataService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getCustomerData();
  }

  public getCustomerData() {
    this.Service.getCustomers().subscribe((data)=>{
      console.log(data);
      this.customer = data;
    }) 
  }

}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <form class="form-inline">
        <div class="input-group mb-2">
            <div class="has-clear">
                <input type="text" name="search" required class="form-control" placeholder="Name" />
                <button class="clear-data" type="reset"><i class="icon-close-bold-sm"></i></button>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2 ml-3">Search</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">City</th>
                    <th scope="col">State</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor = "let customers of customer">
                    <td scope="row">{{customers.value.Name}}</td>
                    <td scope="row">{{customers.value.StateName}}</td>
                    <td scope="row">{{customers.value.CityName}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is an array and not object, so

```
  public getCustomerData() {
    this.Service.getCustomers().subscribe((data)=>{
      console.log(data);
      this.customer = data.value;
    }) 
  }
```

and in your template

```
<tr *ngFor = "let customers of customer">
    <td scope="row">{{customers.Name}}</td>
    <td scope="row">{{customers.StateName}}</td>
    <td scope="row">{{customers.CityName}}</td>
</tr>
```

Or you can just edit your template

```
<tr *ngFor = "let customers of customer.value">
    <td scope="row">{{customers.Name}}</td>
    <td scope="row">{{customers.StateName}}</td>
    <td scope="row">{{customers.CityName}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using | async to access the observable directly in your html

```
<tr *ngFor = "let customer of customers$ | async">
    <td scope="row">{{customer.Name}}</td>
    <td scope="row">{{customer.StateName}}</td>
    <td scope="row">{{customer.CityName}}</td>
</tr>
```

and in your component

```
customers$ : Observable<Customer> = this.getCustomerData();
```

You can update your `getCustomerData` with a map operator to return the list of Customers you have inside *value* property.